# TRRS 3.5mm audio jack wiring to sim868

Tags: audio, connector, wiring

I want to connect a 3.5mm trrs audio connector to sim868.

[image]

The image above is my connector.
But sim868 has four pins as:

1- MIC +

2- MIC -

3- SPK-N

4- SPK-P

As shown in the picture above, the pins of this connector are as follows:

1-S

3-T

2-R

6-SR

I want to use this connector both as a microphone and as a headphone.
Can someone clearly guide me how to connect the connector pins to sim868?
The connector has one MIC pin but the sim868 has two MIC pins, what should I do?

Comment: The pinout on a FC68128 should be very similar to a PJ-302A https://github.com/nathanhborger/PJ-320A_KiCad_Library